# Meaning of - Forgivable lapse in your circumstances

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, phrases

What does the above sentence mean ?

Context: 
Me - I got up late today.
Friend - It is a forgivable lapse in your circumstances.

Is the above sentence correct?  I feel it is not but I'm not able to pinpoint the exact error.

Comment: Friend - Given your circumstances, I'd say that is a forgivable lapse. A comma would help parsing.

Comment: can you write that as an answer so I can mark it as correct

Comment: Sorry, Sonu – I think it more appropriate for ELL, and I never give an  'answer' to questions I consider off-topic (even though I often still provide what I consider to be help).

Answer (score 1):

**Forgivable momentary lapses of common sense**

Your sentence it written in different ways, such as here:

> He could have forgiven the lapses in view of the circumstances.
>   [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=HZJQAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA134&ots=3tGvR5pxoG&dq=a%20forgivable%20lapse%20in%20your%20circumstances&pg=PA134#v=onepage&q&f=false)

- "It is a forgivable lapse, given your circumstances."    or   "It is
  a forgivable lapse, in your circumstance."

may be better grammar.  But the sentence as written is OK.

Context:  your friend is cutting you some slack ... sleeping in.  He knows you are experiencing some tough times.

Answer (score 1):

> It is a forgivable lapse in your circumstances.

In grammatical terms this is ambiguous. It could mean that your *circumstances* have lapsed. That doesn't make much sense.

What it is clearly supposed to mean is, "In your circumstances, it is a forgivable lapse"

"it" of course refers to getting up late, i.e.

"In your circumstances, getting up late is a forgivable lapse"